How to empty InputField if the user change the RadioField?
I'm using shadcn and react-hook-form. I have a Radiobutton here that will open an additional input field if the user selected yes. The problem I'm encountering right now is when the user select yes and fill up the other input field and then he decided to select no. When the form submitted. The additional field is included even though it shouldnt.
Form.tsx
const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof FormSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(FormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      type: 'no',
      dryRunDate: '',
      dryRunStart: '',
      dryRunEnd: '',

    
    }
  });

<Form {...form}>
      <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className="w-2/3 space-y-6">
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="type"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem className="space-y-3">
              <FormLabel>Optional;</FormLabel>
              <FormControl>
                <RadioGroup
                  onValueChange={field.onChange}
                  defaultValue={field.value}
                  className="flex flex-col space-y-1"
                >
                  <FormItem className="flex items-center space-x-3 space-y-0">
                    <FormControl>
                      <RadioGroupItem value="yes" />
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormLabel className="font-normal">yes</FormLabel>
                  </FormItem>
                  <FormItem className="flex items-center space-x-3 space-y-0">
                    <FormControl>
                      <RadioGroupItem value="no" />
                    </FormControl>
                    <FormLabel className="font-normal">no</FormLabel>
                  </FormItem>

                  {hasDryRun === "yes" && (
                    <>
                      <FormField
                        control={form.control}
                        name="dryRunDate"
                        render={({ field }) => (
                          <FormItem>
                            <FormLabel>dryRunDate</FormLabel>
                            <FormControl>
                              <Input type="text" placeholder="date" {...field} />
                            </FormControl>
                            <FormMessage />
                          </FormItem>
                        )}
                      />
                     
                      <FormField
                        control={form.control}
                        name="dryRunStart"
                        render={({ field }) => (
                          <FormItem>
                            <FormLabel>dryRunDate</FormLabel>
                            <FormControl>
                              <Input type="text" placeholder="date" {...field} />
                            </FormControl>
                            <FormMessage />
                          </FormItem>
                        )}
                      />
                     
                      <FormField
                        control={form.control}
                        name="dryRunEnd"
                        render={({ field }) => (
                          <FormItem>
                            <FormLabel>dryRunDate</FormLabel>
                            <FormControl>
                              <Input type="text" placeholder="date" {...field} />
                            </FormControl>
                            <FormMessage />
                          </FormItem>
                        )}
                      />
                     
                    </>
                  )}
                </RadioGroup>
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </Form>


You can add some logic into your onSubmit function that checks whether that field is selected. If not you can delete the conditional property from the form object

In the "no" RadioGroupItem's onFocus or onClicked, you could probably clear the value of fields you want

Update the onValueChange prop of <RadioGroup> as bellow:
onValueChange={(val) => {
  form.resetField("dryRunDate");
  form.resetField("dryRunEnd");
  form.resetField("dryRunStart");
  field.onChange(val);
}}

